# How to smart-indent files automatically on save in Light Table

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I would like to save nicely formatted Clojure code. Eclipse can format code every time a file is saved. It would be nice to have the same in Light Table. Manually, I can do it by selecting all (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>), then running (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) `Editor: Smart indent line(s)`. Is there a way to do it automatically every time a file is saved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override key bindings for save in `Settings: User keymap` like:

```clj
{:+ {:editor {"ctrl-s" [:editor.select-all
                        :smart-indent-selection
                        :editor.selection.clear
                        :save]}}}
```

But you will lost cursor position (it will jump to the end of file). This can be handled with `Marks` plugin. Install the plugin and add command `:lt.plugins.marks/jump-to-large-move-mark` onto last position of commands vector.

Comment: Thanks, @Aleš! At the end I decided to use a separate key binding for re-indenting, because with this solution you cannot undo the formatting if you don't want it (and save the file). In Eclipse, when auto-format on save is used, if you press ctrl+s, then the code is formatted and saved. If you press ctrl+z after that, formatting will be undone and the file will be saved again. Another way is to put `:save` first in the list of commands: this will save and format after, then you can press ctrl+s again to save the formatted version or ctrl+z to undo the formatting (file will be saved still).

Answer (score 3):

new Keymap-Style in actual Lighttable (0.7.2)

Press (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) -> enter "keymap" and select "User keymap"

```
[:editor "ctrl-s" :editor.select-all :smart-indent-selection :editor.selection.clear :save]
```

or with marks plugin

```
[:editor "ctrl-s" :editor.select-all :smart-indent-selection 
:editor.selection.clear :save :lt.plugins.marks/jump-to-large-move-mark]
```